# Match empty collection with Hamcrest's hasItem()

Tags: java, collections, testng, hamcrest

How do I match an empty collection using TestNG and `hasItem` from Hamcrest? This is what I get as a result of one test.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a collection containing email = null phone = null
got: <[]>
```

Here is my matcher class:

```
private static class MyPersonMatcher extends TypeSafeMatcher<Person> {
   private final String email;
   private final String phone;
      public ContactAgentUsageMatcher() {
   }
   public ContactAgentUsageMatcher(String email, String phone, Integer listingId) {
      this.email = email;
      this.phone = phone;
   }
   @Override
   public void describeTo(Description description) {
      description.appendText("email = ");
      description.appendValue(this.email);
      description.appendText(" phone = ");
      description.appendValue(this.phone);
   }
   @Override
   public boolean matchesSafely(ContactAgentUsage contactAgentUsage) {
      if ((this.email == null) && (this.phone == null)) {
         return true;
      }
      else {
         return ObjectUtils.equals(this.email, contactAgentUsage.getEmail())
             && ObjectUtils.equals(this.phone, contactAgentUsage.getPhone());
      }
   }
}
```

The test that fails is

```
assertThat(argument.getAllValues(), hasItem(expectedMatcher));
```

where `expectedMatcher` is provided by data provider. I am not sure what to pass to match this "empty collection" as a result. I am passing default constructor but I know this doesn't work because it creates collection with `null` members.

This is part of my data provider:

```
{ new ContactAgentUsageMatcher()}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom matcher will match any existing `Person` when the configured `email` and `name` are both set to `null`. However, the collection doesn't contain *any* `Person`s to match against. Hamcrest's [`hasItem(matcher)`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.2.1/hamcrest-library-1.2.1-javadoc.jar!/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasItem%28org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) fails the test in this case and is the wrong matcher to use for empty collections.

Here are two workarounds:

1. Change the data provider and tests to take the full matcher including `hasItem`. For the above case you would pass [`emptyIterable`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/hamcrest/hamcrest-library/1.2.1/hamcrest-library-1.2.1-javadoc.jar!/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#emptyIterable%28%29). The downside is that you'll need to tell the Java compiler which generic type it should use which will clutter the tests.
2. Create a second test to handle the data sets that produce an empty collection.